# Json object to java arraylist

Tags: java, json, gson

I have pass two values from ajax to my servlet.

I used

```
JsonObject data = new Gson().fromJson(request.getReader(), JsonObject.class);
System.out.println(data);
```

and this is the output

> {"0":"31/01/2017","1":"19/01/2017"}

Now I want to convert this data into a java arraylist but not really sure how.

I tried

```
Gson googleJson = new Gson();
JsonObject data = googleJson.fromJson(request.getReader(), JsonObject.class);
System.out.println(data);
JsonArray jsonArr = data.getAsJsonArray();
// jsonArr.

ArrayList jsonObjList = googleJson.fromJson(jsonArr, ArrayList.class);
for(int i=0; i< jsonObjList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(jsonObjList.get(i));
}
```

But got an error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.

---

Someone help me please? thanks.

Comment: you can use something like `data.getAsString("0")` and `data.getAsString("1")` because it's a `JSONObject`

Comment: what if the size of my data is not fixed?  meaning the data can be more than 2.

Comment: one way is use `entrySet()` and fetch all keys and value as mapentry and other way is create POJO class with corresponding mapping fields mean Hashmap inside POJO

Comment: possible to use Arraylist instead?

Comment: i guess there will be surely a way to make it as ArrayList , you can mention it in your question as requirement , someone will surely guide you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create instance of `JsonArray` then add json element to that array using key.

Here is your solution :

```
Gson googleJson = new Gson();
JsonObject data = googleJson.fromJson(request.getReader(), JsonObject.class);
System.out.println(data);
JsonArray jsonArr = new JsonArray();

for(Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : data.entrySet()) {
    jsonArr.add(data.get(entry.getKey()));
}

ArrayList jsonObjList = googleJson.fromJson(jsonArr, ArrayList.class);
for(int i = 0; i < jsonObjList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(jsonObjList.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Json to be a valid JsonArray object you should have it to a proper format. Can you change your json string return from your ajax? If yes you should change it to something like this:

```
Gson googleJson = new Gson();
JsonObject data = googleJson.fromJson("{test: [{\"0\":\"31/01/2017\"},{\"1\":\"19/01/2017\"}]}", JsonObject.class);
System.out.println(data);
JsonArray jsonArr = data.getAsJsonArray("test");

ArrayList jsonObjList = googleJson.fromJson(jsonArr, ArrayList.class);
for(int i=0; i< jsonObjList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(jsonObjList.get(i));
}
```

If not you should parse it by your self and convert it to everything you want.